# Show text if date is today

Tags: php, date, calendar, show

I need to show (today) text if date is today. How do I do that!
I tried everything but cant find the right anwser that's why Im asking here.
Here is the piece of codeI have right now.

```
$mod_list.= '<ul class="upcoming-events"><li>
<div class="date">
    <span><span class="day">'.date($dateformat,$datetime_start).'</span>
    <span><span class="month">'.date($datemonth,$datetime_start).'</span>
    <span><span class="year">'.date($dateyear,$datetime_start).'</span>
</div>';
```

I want to show it just behind the last `</span>`
It is for event calendar and I want to show the text TODAY on the exact day of the event.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `I need to show (today) text if date is today` - let that sink in for a second.

Comment: you can compare the calendar date: `date('Y-m-d') == $calendar_date`

Comment: You have some unclosed `<span>` or why do you have them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(date('Y-m-d',$datetime_start)==date('Y-m-d')){
    //it's today! put code here
 }else{
    //it's not today
 }
```

If you don't use the second parameter in the date() function, it uses the current time.  So comparing their date to today is that simple.

Comment: Pretty hard to judge much at all from the OP's code, as (s)he shows no initialization of variables, hence my trollish answer.  It's always today ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the whole Code for what I'm using, it is actualy a droplet for showing the event calendar in my sidebar.

```
    //:Show next #N events
//:
// Get_Concerts
global $database, $wb;

setlocale (LC_ALL, 'sl_SI.UTF-8'); //za vse kategorije 
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'sl_SI.UTF-8'); //za datumske funkcije

// Show how many items, defaults to 10?
if ( !isset($max) ){ $max = 10; };

// year and month and section defaults
if(!isset($year)) {$year = date('Y', time()); }
if(!isset($month)) {$month = date('n', time()); }
if(!isset($section_id)) {$section_id = 0 ; }


// Set dateformat to suit your needs, add timeformat if needed
$dateformat = 'd'; // Standard php date formats
$datemonth = 'M'; // Standard php date formats
$dateyear = 'Y'; // Standard php date formats

// Fetch base page link, if event_id = set
$extrasql = '';
$page_id = 0;
$page_link ='';

if ($section_id<>0) { 
$extrasql = " section_id = '".$section_id."' AND "; 
$sql = "SELECT page_id FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."sections WHERE section_id = '".$section_id."'";
$result = $database->query($sql);
if ( $result->numRows() > 0 ) {
while( $row = $result->fetchRow() ) {
$page_id = $row['page_id'];
}
}
if ($page_id <> 0) {
$sql = "SELECT link FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."pages WHERE page_id = '".$page_id."'";
$result = $database->query($sql);
if ( $result->numRows() > 0 ) {
while( $row = $result->fetchRow() ) {
$page_link = page_link($row['link']);
}
}
}
}

// Set start- and end date for query
// $datestart = "$year-$month-1"; ORIGINAL = show all events in this month
$datestart = date("Y-m-d"); // ALTERNATIVE = show all events in this month, starting today
$dateend = "$year-$month-".cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month,$year);
$mod_list = "";

// Fetch the items
$sql = "SELECT DAY(date_start) AS day, id, custom1, date_start, time_start, date_end, time_end, name FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."mod_procalendar_actions WHERE ".$extrasql." date_start >='$datestart' AND public_stat = 0 ORDER BY date_start,time_start LIMIT 0, ".$max." ";
$mod_query = $database->query($sql);
while ( $row =& $mod_query->fetchRow()){
// Build url like : pages/kalendar.php?id=2&detail=1 
$page_url = $page_link.'?id='.$row['id'].'&amp;detail=1';
$ds = $row['date_start']." ".substr($row['time_start'],0,5);
$de = $row['date_end']." ".substr($row['time_end'],0,5);
$datetime_start = mktime(substr($ds,11,2),substr($ds,14,2),0,substr($ds,5,2),substr($ds,8,2),substr($ds,0,4));
$datetime_end = mktime(substr($de,11,2),substr($de,14,2),0,substr($de,5,2),substr($de,8,2),substr($de,0,4));
if ($row['time_start'] !== $printTime) {
    $printTime = $row['time_start'];




$mod_list.= '<ul class="upcoming-events"><li>
<div class="date"><span><span class="day">'.date($dateformat,$datetime_start).'</span><span><span class="month">'.date($datemonth,$datetime_start).'</span><span><span class="year">'.date($dateyear,$datetime_start).'</span>


</div>';



$mod_list.= '<div class="event-content"><h6><a href="'.$page_url.'">'.$row["name"].'</a></h6>
<ul class="event-meta"><li><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>'.substr($printTime,0,5).'<sup>h</sup></li>
<!-- <li><i class="fa fa-info-circle">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>'.$row["custom1"].'</li> --></ul></div></li></ul>';


   }
$mod_list .= "<hr>";

}
$mod_list .= '<a href="[wblink13]" class="button transparent button-arrow" style="margin-top:-10px;">Napovednik</a><br></br>';

 return $mod_list;
```

Here is the link to the site, [LINK](http://www.bi-center.eu) you'll notice a TEST event which is created for today, I want a little TODAY text to be shown right beside the HOUR on the right.

I hope this helps more, Thank you

R.

Comment: did you see the other answer?  wherever you have the date, use that if/else to write something when it's today and something else when it isn't today.

Comment: Yes I tried and it works I just don't know how to style it or give it some class, can you help me with that, pls. (I'm not a coder). I woul need it somewhere in between this code if Im right.

$mod_list.= '<div class="event-content"><h6><a href="'.$page_url.'">'.$row["name"].'</a></h6>
<ul class="event-meta"><li><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>'.substr($printTime,0,5).'<sup>h</sup></li>
<!-- <li><i class="fa fa-info-circle">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>'.$row["custom1"].'</li> --></ul></div></li></ul>';

   }  Because now it is shown in my header.

Comment: Ok, forget it I got it, thank you very much, helped me a lot ;) It's working great ;)